# Java One-liner Scanner from URL Text file

Tags: java, url, java.util.scanner

In java, what code do I need to get from "http://www.mysite.com/text.txt" to a Scanner that parses the resulting text contained in the site in as few lines as possible.

Comment: Please define: `parsing`

Comment: You can do this in as few lines as possible, or you can do it with robust code.  Not both at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
URL yahoo = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                yahoo.openStream()));

    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);

    in.close();
```

---

**Reference**

- [Reading URL in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html)

Comment: Don't know what the down-vote was for, but I think this is the most robust answer. I've tried the two below and had less success.

As a one liner:     

`Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(segmentationpath).openStream())));`

Comment: How can I write this to a word doc?

Answer (score 8):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new URL("http://www.mysite.com/text.txt").openStream());
```

Comment: Are there any advantages to using one of the options which require more code, such as the accepted answer seen above?

Answer (score 4):

Taken from [here](http://ostas.blogspot.com/2006/12/java-scanner-read-whole-page-at-once.html), not tested

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://www.mysite.com/text.txt").openConnection();
String text = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
```

Answer (score 1):

an `HTTP GET` in one line of code: (using Java 8)

```
String doc = new Scanner(new URL(strUrl).openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```